# How to change the color of a cell if a certain value of clicks is met?

Tags: javascript

Well as mentioned in the title. I need to find a way to change the color from green to red once a value of anything greater than 4 clicks is met. I have tried researching multiple times but I try to mash up the codes it just won't work together properly. So I have just placed the original code instead. I just need to find out the proper codes to be used, I am a student so I don't really have much knowledge on coding. Thank you for taking your time to read this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SA1</title>

<style type="text/css">

body
{
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:20px;
padding:40px;

}

th{
color:black;
background-color:grey;
text-align:center;
padding:25px;

}

.green
{
 background-color:green;
 padding:50px;
 text-align:center;
 height: 50px;
}

.red
{
 background-color:red;
 padding:50px;
 text-align:center;
 height: 50px;
}


td{
 padding:20px;

}

.h{
color:white;
background-color:black;
text-align:center;
padding:25px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var p = prompt("Password is password")
     if (p !== "password"){
     document.getElementById("nope").innerHTML = ("<h1>Access Denied. Try     Adding Hours.</h1>");
}

var a = 0;
function A() {
    a += 1;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
};

var b = 0;
function B() {
    b += 1;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b;
};

var c = 0;
function C() {
    c += 1;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = c;
};

function E(){
    var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
    document.getElementById("E").innerHTML = e
}

function F(){
    var f = document.getElementById("f").value;
    document.getElementById("F").innerHTML = f
}

function G(){
    var g = document.getElementById("g").value;
    document.getElementById("G").innerHTML = g
}

function save() {
  var date = new Date();
  var n = date.toDateString();
  var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = n + ' ' + time
}

</script>

<h3 id="nope">GreenSlip Counter</h3>
<p id ="time"></p>
<p id= "nope"><button onclick="save()">Save</button></p>


<hr>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th id="E"><input type="text" id="e">
<button onclick="E()">Name</button>
</th>
<th id="F"><input type="text" id="f">
<button onclick="F()">Name</button>
</th>
<th id="G"><input type="text" id="g">
<button onclick="G()">Name</button>
</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="green" onclick="A()"></td>
<td class="green" onclick="B()"></td>
<td class="green" onclick="C()"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="h">
<td>Hours: <a id="a">0</a></td>
<td>Hours: <a id="b">0</a></td>
<td>Hours: <a id="c">0</a></td>
</tr>

</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried, and post only the minimum code needed to understand the problem.

Comment: You look like you're keeping track of the number of clicks well. Now you just need to figure out how set a class `if` a condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an id to each of the td's with the class "green".  Let's assume we added changed `<td class="green" onclick="A()"></td>` to `<td class="green" onclick="A()" id="a_click_target"></td>`

Then, we could update functions A, B, and C like so:

```
function A() {
    a += 1;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
    if (a >= 4){
       document.getElementById("a_click_target").classList.remove("green");
       document.getElementById("a_click_target").classList.add("red");
    }
};
```